# How to remote-control a linux-desktop-pc from a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: remote, networking

I tried to do this by installing Remmina on the Pi (Raspbian) and setting up Vino on my Ubuntu Desktop to allow the Pi to control it.

It worked, but there was a huge latency which made it almost impossible to really make use of this setup. I tried to configure Remmina "as fast as possible".

What can I do/configure to make this connection more efficient?

Comment: what is your network connection between the Pi and Ubuntu?

Comment: 100Mbit Ethernet. Sorry I forgot to mention that.